# create-react-app installs, but fails to run with "start"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

On Windows 10 with NodeJS portable version 12.4.0 (I'm on a corporate computer and don't have access to install NodeJS).

When I run `npx create-react-app myApp`, it runs fine with no errors. I should mention I have an existing app (created months ago) which still runs fine on the same machine, but uses an older version of react-scripts.

When I run `npm run start`, i'm presented with this error:

````
events.js:177
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:3000/' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! req@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the req@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.```
````

Comment: You are probably missing C:\Windows\System32 in your systems PATH variable in the git shell.. Try to run: export PATH=$PATH:C:\Windows\System32 . And then re-run the command.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this as it requires admin privileges, which I do not have. I'm using `$env:Path = "c:\nodejs"`  in PowerShell to set the PATH. This also works with my previous app. 

Shortly after posting this question I noticed that if I change the "react-scripts" in package.json to `2.1.8` from the default `3.0.1`, then running `npm i`, it works. 

So what gives? what's up with react-scripts 3.0.1?

Comment: Ok, I think you will have to downgrade you react-scripts version then. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your environment variables when using react-scripts@3.1.8
See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6985

Just downgrade you react-scripts' version and it should work:

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend handling that error. If you need something more specific than that, it seems like we would need to see the code.

You can also use a process manager such as PM2 to automatically restart your bot whenever it crashes.